# Please add a title and link when inserting a Hyperlink to other StackOverflow posts

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Currently it works this way:

You select a text to link, click the hyperlink button and paste the url. When you hit OK the text you selected is now linked. There is even a title feature in the current hyperlink but this only fills out the title attribute of the link.

But when inserting links to other SO questions, or when generating a collection of links this becomes a pain to juggle. So I suggest a small change.

If you do it the old way and select a text and click the hyperlink button, there are two fields. One is filled out "Title" since you selected a text. And the other is a url.

If you click the hyperlink button without selecting a text, both fields are empty and it will be inserted where the text cursor is.

Answer (score 3):

How about someone creating some browser helpers or add-ins so we can copy a hyperlink *with the text and title, etc* then paste it into SO, properly formatted? I can do that in certain other web-based forums, and it's very convenient.

Ok, it's at least convenient when it's possible to select the link and not, for instance, the table it's embedded in. But when it works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly things changed since this question was asked long ago, but currently using the URL button (or hitting Ctrl-L) without first selecting text inserts *and pre-selects* the default link text:

[image: Result after using insert hyperlink button]

Simply start typing the link text after that?